# using 'objc_setAssociatedObject' with 'struct' (Swift 3)

Tags: swift

```swift
protocol MyProtocol { }
var handle: UInt8 = 0
extension MyProtocol {
    var myField: Any? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &handle)
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &handle, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}
struct MyObject: MyProtocol {} // works if 'struct' is changed to 'class'
var myObject = MyObject()
myObject.myField = "123456"
myObject.myField // nil
```

Is there any way of using associated objects with 'struct', or any other technique allowing to define a field in protocol extension and not in 'struct' itself?

Comment: I don't know why you want to do this, but generally going against how Swift is designed is a bad thing.

Comment: objc_setAssociatedObject is from the Objective-C runtime and can only be used with *objects,* i.e. instances of a class. – A struct is a fixed-size value, adding a property would change its memory layout.

Comment: @MartinR - indeed i figured that much. Can you suggest an alternative solution to provide protocol-defined properties to be used in structs extending it? It really has to be struct (not class), and there will be a lot of instances of it created and deleted quite often.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to add additional properties to an existing struct.